# Http - use of "upgrade" header value

Tags: html, http, web

I know that websockets (Html5) uses upgrade header to let the server know that the session would be using same port (80) but a different protocol.

Are there any other elements (be it in HTML5 or others) that use "upgrade". I need to find something online that uses "upgrade" in order to test some behavior.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "HTML5".

Another protocol that will use the Upgrade header field is HTTP/2.0.

Comment: I know. is there a website where I can see this in action ? (e.g. wireshark capture to show me "upgrade" happening)